# Grails 3 (unsaved) instance issue while fetching from database (GORM)

Tags: grails-orm, grails-3.0

I am getting an issue while fetching from the database using GORM like 
UserRole.findByUser(User.first())
 or using any kind of dynamic finders for fetching object.

It is always returning an object in an Unsaved state.

com.tothenew.cat.UserRole : (unsaved)

Can anyone explain why this is happening.

Comment: Is it possible you are creating the UserRole in the same transaction in which you are invoking the finder?

Comment: Or possibly the save operation you believe you've performed failed for some reason.  Check the entity's errors property after trying to save.

Comment: Data for UserRole is already persisting in the database i have verified it. But still objects of this class always returned with an unsaved state.

Comment: Was there a resolution for this issue?